# (Python) cannot open the file from directory

Tags: python

I want to open the file as output.

> It turned out "exit"

However, I want to `read` the file or `write` the file. Through the test, it seems not
the `IOError`. How to open the file?

I tried several codes and still could not find the way to open it.

```
try:
    my_file_handle=open("/Users/name/Desktop/Trip.docx")
except IOError:
    print("File not found or path is incorrect")
finally:
    print("exit")
```

Then, I changed "docx" to "doc" and add 'r' mode and call it.

I tried:

```
    try:
        my_file_handle=open('/Users/name/Desktop/Trip.doc','r')
        my_file_handle.read()
        print("hi")
    except IOError:
        print("File not found or path is incorrect")
    finally:
        print("exit")
```

> it turned out "exit" and   my_file_handle.read()
>
> > File"/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
> >         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
> >
> > UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position
> >     0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: What’s your error message? I believe when opening a file you need to specify whether you’re reading, writing, etc.

Comment: I want to read it.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the open file? `docx` files are zip files so you should open them in binary mode (`mode='rb'`). Also you can open them with [`zipfile.ZipFile('/Users/name/Desktop/Trip.docx')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile)  and access the archived files.

Comment: I tried "rb". It could not work.

Comment: Again, what do you want to do with the file once opened? Perhaps a library like [`python-docx`](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/) would be more useful.

Comment: I had read python documentation.

Comment: Anyway, your code will either successfully open the file and assign it to `my_file_handle`, or it will fail with `OSError` (use that rather than `IOError` in Python 3). Either way something should be printed - your error message or a traceback. And `exit` will always be printed because the `finally` block will always execute. Try opening the file without any exception handling at all... just type it into a terminal and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to move any except. Or just to use my_file_handle. don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested if the file is actually open at the end of the block? Because I think you'll find it is. The code in the 'finally' part of a try: except: block is obeyed regardless of whether there is an exception or not.

From the python documentation:

If finally is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The try clause is executed, including any except and else clauses. If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. The finally clause is executed. If there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the finally clause. If the finally clause raises another exception, the saved exception is set as the context of the new exception. If the finally clause executes a return or break statement, the saved exception is discarded:

Comment: No, it still could not open the file.

Comment: Curious - and there is no traceback? Or other sign of an exception?

Comment: Actually, can you try this for me? "with open(/Users/name/Dexktop/Trip.docx" as f: <newline><indent>r=f.read(20)<newline>' where <..> are the actions within the angle brackets and see if r contains anything afterewards?

Comment: From my comment in reply to @Caligary above can you try specifying a second parameter to the open of 'rb'. The  b is for binary. .docx file are in effect sipped .doc files.

Comment: try as f-->I do not know if my key-in wrong. It shows invalid syntax.

Comment: try putting print('hi') after the open if the try part of the block, if the open is throwing a suppressed exception it shouldn't execute.

Comment: OK now put in the test: 'if my_file_handle is None:' above the print (and indent the print!) and try again.

Comment: It still returned exit.

Comment: Yes, but did it return 'hi'? if it didn't there is something in the file pointer, i.e. open returned something so we need to find out what.

Comment: It returned "hi" and "exit".

Comment: Ah!! light dawns!!! Can you thoroughly check the filename? I suspect it doesn't exist. OK when you open a file in read mode if the file does not exist on linux a FileNotFoundError exception is raised. It looks as though the behaviour is either different on mac or the 'finally' clause is somehow suppressing the exception (it shouldn't be!)

Comment: I tried another file.-->tried "error.pages"-->the file really exist. and it returned "hi" and "exit". And tried another wrong file(errors.pages)-->it returned "File not found or path is incorrect" and "exit".

Comment: OK, I think we now need to try this outside a try: except  block, so we get a traceback of any error. Can you do that?

Comment: I tried "except BlockingIOError", and it returned "hi" and "exit".

Comment: I added "my_file_handle.read()". It turned out new error message as the newly edited content.

Comment: As I said earlier you need to open it 'rb'!

Comment: use 'rb',then returned "hi" and "exit".

Comment: But you read(() is now complaining that it can't decode using 'utf-8' This means 1. it successfully opened,  and 2. the content is binary, which needs 'rb'. so no decode takes place.

Comment: it turned out "found 0 to do items in 0 files"

Comment: I opened a file but I use URL to open. that is another way.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the file, you have to specify your intensions.
For writing that would be:

```
    my_file_handle=open("/Users/name/Desktop/Trip.docx","w")
```

Comment: No, you don't but if you don't r is implied. Actually, that gives me an idea... is this because  .docx files are binary?

Comment: I tried another -->.pages . It still could not work.